# Get error when QgsVectorLayer is not valid

Tags: pyqgis, wfs, qgis-2.18, qgsvectorlayer

In QGIS 2.18.16, with a custom plugin, I tried this code to create a new vector layer for WFS:

```
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "my WFS layer", "WFS", False)
if not v_layer.isValid():
    print v_layer.error()            # 1
    print v_layer.error().message()  # 2
    print v_layer.error().summary()  # 3
```

- print 1: is a qgis._core.QgsError object
- print 2: empty string
- print 3: qgis crash with segmentation fault

I need to get an error type or the WFS response to understand, for example, if the url is not correct or if the service is down.